# Cron Job - why does my php script select not only one day (as I want it to work) which is 7 days forwads from right now but it selects

Tags: php, mysql, cron

```
ID  | Client  |    Data    | Hosting   | Price |
    |         |            |           |       |
    |         | 2017-11-23 | Heineken  | 500   |
    |         | 2017-11-22 | Hestia    | 200   |
    |         | 2017-11-21 | Bravo     | 200   |
    |         | 0000-00-00 |           |       |
    |         | 0000-00-00 |           |       |
```

Why when I want the PHP code to select only the record with date 23-11-2017 which is 7 days from right now (16-11-2017) my scirpt somehow selects EACH SINGLE DAY from now (16-11-2017) up to 23-22-2017, namely 2017-11-22 and 2017-11-21...(above is my MySql table from which I select mentioned records)

This is my cronejob.php code:

```
<?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'stdeja_genek', 'haslo', 'stdeja_genek');

    $tbl_2 = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM klienci WHERE date(Data) BETWEEN CURTIME() AND DATE_ADD(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);");

    if($tbl_2->num_rows == 1) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        foreach($tbl_2 as $email => $details) {        
            $fullname = $details['Klient'] . ' ' . $details['Data'];

            $mail->addAddress('piterdeja@gmail.com');
            $mail->setFrom('system_przypomnien_hosting@powiadomienia.pl');
            $mail->Subject = "Hosting - system przypomnień";
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Body = "W dniu {$details['Data']} kończy się hosting klientowi {$details['Klient']} na KWOTĘ {$details['Cena']}, hosting to {$details['Hosting']}";

            if ($mail->send())
                echo "Formularz został wysłany. Postaramy się odpowiedzieć jak najszybciej.";
            else
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }             
    }  
?>
```

Comment: `date(Data) BETWEEN CURTIME() AND DATE_ADD(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);`  is wierd you are filtering a DATE with CURTIME() looks like you need to replace CURTIME() with CURDATE()

Comment: heh thanks...maby that is it :P I will test repacing every CURTIME() with CURDATE().....I  changed it to : 

SELECT * FROM klienci WHERE date(Data) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait... you want it to select one day 7 days from now, but you’re using `BETWEEN`. Why not just use `=`?

Comment: I changed it to:

$tbl_2 = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM klienci WHERE date(Data) = CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);");

does it select only one day now?

Comment: `WHERE date(Data) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`

Comment: I changed it to SELECT * FROM klienci WHERE date(Data) = CURDATE()+7;

...works as well